# Can I install the F# compiler stand alone?

Tags: f#

I looking to install the F# compiler to use on the command line. Is there a place to download it, without downloading visual studio and all the other stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes -- at least, you can download the F# 2.0 compiler easily:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=600

The sources for the F# 3.0 compiler were released on Codeplex recently, so if you want to use that one you'll need to download them and compile everything yourself; or you can wait for a downloadable release, which should be available soon.

Comment: Compilation is easy! Hurray for (almost, semi-, wanna-be) open source!

Answer (score 0):

[make a standalone F# 3.0 works without Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421873/is-there-a-way-to-install-f-3-0-without-visual-studio/14788567#14788567)

1. First, find a workstation with F# 3.0 installed. (source)
2. Duplicate all the things to destination workstation.

> ```
> -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#
> -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp
> -> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp*
> ```

3. Install .NET 4.5 at destination.
4. Export all the registry item with FSC.exe string to destination.
5. Export all the registry item with FSharp string to destination.