# Is F# 3.0 available on Visual Studio 2010 professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-3.0

I would love to try f# 3.0 but I only have visual studio 2010 professional.  I know F# 3.0  comes installed with visual studio 2012 out of the box, but I'm not in a position where I can upgrade to vs2012 yet.

A recent msdn post by [Don Syme](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/24/announcing-the-f-3-0-open-source-code-drop.aspx) hints that it can be used with visual studio 2010, but there doesn't seem to be any resources or explanations at how this is possible.

Quoting the article:

> ...to use F# 3.0 in Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010, including with the free tools, go to fsharp.net

But of course [fsharp.net](http://fsharp.net) just goes to an [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388569.aspx) that pushes visual studio 2012.

I'm also apparently not the only one who's been asking about this if you look at the comments in the post.

Has anyone had any luck with this or do I need to use visual studio 2012 to use f# 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I went straight to the source and [tweeted](https://twitter.com/dsyme/status/282059158742790145) at Don Syme my question. You cannot use f# 3.0 with visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

F# 3.0 is part of Visual Studio 2012 for now, including VS Express. A standalone version is in the works ([Is there a way to install F# 3.0 without Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421873/is-there-a-way-to-install-f-3-0-without-visual-studio))

Comment: Yes, I saw that post. However, I mentioned I was aware it's in visual studio 2012. While it's nice they are doing that, I'm not interested in a standalone version -  I'm looking for one that integrates with visual studio 2010.  The post I linked to indicated it can be used with visual studio 2010, I'm just not sure where any of those resources exist, since fsharp.net just redirects to an msdn page pushing visual studio 2012

Comment: It is possible to open the same project in VS 2012 and VS 2010 SP1 so you could open your solution in VS 2012 Express whenever you need to work with F# 3 and provide the compiled assemblies to anyone else who can't install VS Express yet. Not the prettiest solution, but it works. Side-by-side installation is painless

Comment: Yes, certainly a suggestion, however that's a pretty hacky solution, especially if you are using F# libraries mixed with C# libraries. Doing it with two IDE's you lose resharper since vs express doesn't allow plugins.  Seems odd to me given that one of the main researchers on F# (Don Syme) says it should work and yet nowhere are the resources to do this