# F# with Visual Studio Express/Professional/etc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, f#

I am going to learn F#. In my lecturer notes, they have simply asked to open VS 2010, open project, select other languages and select F# ! I have VS 2010 express, and everything is separated into different software like Visual C++, Visual C# etc, there is no F# !

In this thread ([Is F# 3.0 available on Visual Studio 2010 professional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975644/is-f-3-0-available-on-visual-studio-2010-professional)) I found it is in VS 2012 express so I downloaded it. But, again I can't find F#!

How to make a F# project in VS express? Please help!

**EDIT**

At least, is this is available in Visual Studio 2010 Professional? Please help!

Comment: @JohnPalmer: Thanks a lot for the reply. Basically I am a Java programmer and yea, C++ too. I have no much experience with VS. Can you please help me with step by step instructions, with related download links? I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @JohnPalmer: And yes, VS 2012 express is better because they will definitely run and compile my code with VS 2010 full version and not VS 2012. Please help

Comment: In vs 2010 pro you should be able to use http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13450

Comment: @JohnPalmer: So, I need to install VS 2010 PROFESSIONAL and that F# plugin. Right? Please help, I have no exp. with VS rather than visual C++

Comment: install either VS 2010 PRO or the free shell http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=115 and then the F# plugin

Answer (score 3):

Download Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web (it is important, you cannot use F# with  Visual Studio Express 2012 for Desktop or other), then install [F# Tools for Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34675). Full description how to do this is on [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-f-tools-for-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But, I am not going to make web apps! Please help

Comment: Look at this youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4R9EfFNgLU it show how to write desktop app in VS 2012 for Web